# Display single double width chars in iterm3

Tags: terminal, iterm, unicode

I have a battery-emoji in my prompt when the laptop is on battery power. Because this is a double width char and iterm has issues with it, my prompt is broken. One char after the prompt sign is swallowed because iterm calculates wrong terminal width.

To be clear: I have no issue with the emoji overlapping its next char or anything. I deliberately put it at the end of the line and I'm happy with that. I cannot put anything after the battery emoji because of the double width issues but this is *not the problem I need to solve here*.

The problem is that iTerm calculates a wrong width for the line where the emoji is (which is my prompt) and I want to know if there is a way to tell iTerm to calculate that correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107435/emoji-display-issue-in-vim-with-tmux/52142277#52142277